# Pandas error 302; read_html()

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso importar uma tabela que está em html utilizando pandas, mas ao tentar fazer isso o mesmo me retorna erro.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbwMPI0sDBxNXAOMwrzCjA0sjIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wNnUwNHfxcnSwBgIDUyhCvA5EawAjxsKckMjDDI9FQE-F4ca/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0K8DBC0QPVN93KQ10G1/res/id=historicoHTML/c=cacheLevelPage/=/'

tabela_megasena = pd.read_html(url)
```

Segue informações referente ao erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d9298fc7ed7e> in <module>()
----> 1 tabela_megasena = pd.read_html(url)

32 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    743                 len(visited) >= self.max_redirections):
    744                 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code,
--> 745                                 self.inf_msg + msg, headers, fp)
    746         else:
    747             visited = new.redirect_dict = req.redirect_dict = {}

HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

Poderiam me dar uma luz e explicar o do por que esse loop infinito está acontecendo, e se possível

Answer (score 1):

O problema está sendo gerado por múltiplos redirecionamentos (erro 30X)

Olhando o HTML, existem muitos rowspan e colspan; e isso irá bagunçar o dataframe.

A solução apresentada usa:

- [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) para buscar a página
- [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) para extrair a tabela
- [rows](https://pypi.org/project/rows/) para fazer a mágica de ler o html
- [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas2/) para ter o dataframe
- [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) para limpar o html

### Instalando bibliotecas

```
pip install requests
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install rows
pip install "rows[html]"
pip install pandas
```

**Nota** Talvez seja necessária alguma complementar como a `html5lib` ou outra

### Carregando bibliotecas

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import requests
import rows

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import BytesIO
```

### Carregando a página

```
url = 'http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbwMPI0sDBxNXAOMwrzCjA0sjIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wNnUwNHfxcnSwBgIDUyhCvA5EawAjxsKckMjDDI9FQE-F4ca/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0K8DBC0QPVN93KQ10G1/res/id=historicoHTML/c=cacheLevelPage/=/'

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
```

### Usando o BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

tabela = soup.find("table")

# limpando tabelas dentro da tabela
for tag in tabela.find_all('table'):
    _ = tag.replaceWith('')

# encontrando linhas
soup_tr = tabela.findAll("tr")
```

### HACK

```
lista_tr = list(soup_tr)
lista_tr[0] = lista_tr[1]
```

**Nota 1** o primeiro item da lista é uma linha (tr) vazia)
**Nota 2** estou repetindo o primeiro item da lista, pois o `rows` está ignorando ele. (não sei o motivo)

### Transformando a lista em string e limpando comentários

```
s = "".join([str(l) for l in lista_tr])
s = "<table>" + s + "</table>"
s = re.sub("(<!--.*?-->)", "", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

### Usando a biblioteca rows

```
table = rows.import_from_html(BytesIO(bytes(s, encoding='utf-8')))
```

### Jogando em um dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(table.__dict__["_rows"])
```

O dataframe será:

```
>>> df.head()

   0                   1           2     3     4     5     6   ...    15    16    17    18   19   20 21
0   2  Belo Horizonte, MG  18/03/1996   9.0  37.0  39.0  41.0  ...  None  0,00  0,00  0,00  NAO  SIM
1   3        Brasília, DF  25/03/1996  10.0  11.0  29.0  30.0  ...  None  0,00  0,00  0,00  NAO  SIM
2   4     Santo André, SP  01/04/1996   1.0   5.0   6.0  27.0  ...  None  0,00  0,00  0,00  SIM  SIM
3   5        Brasília, DF  08/04/1996   1.0   2.0   6.0  16.0  ...  None  0,00  0,00  0,00  SIM  SIM
4   6        Brasília, DF  15/04/1996   7.0  13.0  19.0  22.0  ...  None  0,00  0,00  0,00  SIM  SIM

[5 rows x 22 columns]
```

**Nota 3** TODO: Aplicar o nome das colunas

Comment: Muito obrigado pela colaboração, Paulo. A principio deu um problema relacionado a "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long", este eu resolvi, porém agora tem outro problema relacionado a "AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape". Caso eu venha conseguir resolver eu trago o resultado aqui.

Comment: É nesta linha `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')`?

Comment: import rows.plugins as plugins
  File "C:\Users\atendimentopcp300_01\Desktop\Antony\Blue Challenge\venv\lib\site-packages\rows\plugins\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import plugin_html as html
  File "C:\Users\atendimentopcp300_01\Desktop\Antony\Blue Challenge\venv\lib\site-packages\rows\plugins\plugin_html.py", line 43, in <module>
    unescape = HTMLParser().unescape
AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Vc instalou o “rows[html]”?